# Como formatar o CPF corretamente em Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
test = input ("CPF: ")
```

Quando o digitado o CPF fica:

```
12345678900
```

Mas quando eu retornar esse `input` ele volte:

```
123.456.789-00
```

Como que eu faço isso em Python?

Comment: Veja https://wiki.python.org.br/Cpf , é tranquilo aplicar a mask

Comment: Ah! Pra esse caso eu tenho que criar uma classe só para o CPF.

Comment: é só pegar os grupos de números e concatenar com a pontuação.

Comment: Para nada precisa criar classe. Nada. Classe é algo que pode ser útil em casos específicos apenas por uma questão de organização de código, mas elas são sempre opcionais. Sempre.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deve ser incluído um teste se o CPF possui 11 dígitos e preencher com zeros a esquerda se forem menos dígitos, desta forma a formatação fica correta para CPFs que começam com zero

```
teste = input("CPF: ") # 12345678900
if len(teste) < 11:
    teste = teste.zfill(11)
cpf = '{}.{}.{}-{}'.format(teste[:3], teste[3:6], teste[6:9], teste[9:])
print(cpf) # 123.456.789-00
```

Comment: Refatorando essa solução chegamos em 
```cpf = '{}{}{}.{}{}{}.{}{}{}-{}{}'.format(*cpf)```

Answer (score 5):

Se for mesmo essa formatação sempre, então concordo com o @Maniero em comentário, não precisa de classe para isso de todo, podes fazer assim:

```
teste = input("CPF: ") # 12345678900
cpf = '{}.{}.{}-{}'.format(teste[:3], teste[3:6], teste[6:9], teste[9:])
print(cpf) # 123.456.789-00
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/LG2c/1)

Answer (score 4):

É simples assim:

```
test = input("CPF: ") 
cpf = test[:3] + "." + test[3:6] + "." + test[6:9] + "-" + test[9:]
print(cpf)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/IPb1v6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cfxytore-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/FormatCpf.py).

Comment: Hehe, exatamente o mesmo

Comment: Não tem como inventar

Comment: Sim, bigown e Miguel! Pra mim essa é a forma mais simples. Já que eu estou aprendendo a linguagem agora.

O método de criar uma classe que o Antharis passou já acho mais evoluído pra mim.

Essa concatenação em Python é muito simples! Pelo amor de Deus! Python é bom demais!

Valeu galera pelas dicas! Trabalho do tamanho do mundo que o professor passou.

Comment: Exato, de acordo

Comment: @SandsonCosta nunca cai de amores por classes. Só as use quando dominar muito bem o procedural, quando entender **muito** sobre OOP e quando for realmente útil. O pessoa faz tudo assim porque caem em martketing. Fazem sem saber porque estão fazendo. Nunca faça nada que não sabe porque está fazendo, porque é útil e benéfico. O arroz com feijão resolve melhor a maioria das coisas. O que não quer dizer que não tenha que evoluir sempre.

Comment: @Miguel não apaga não

Comment: Era só para não haver duas iguais, mas vou usar format na minha para ficar diferente @bigown, obgado

Answer (score 0):

Se desejas utilizar **f-String** para formatar a saída do **CPF**, pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
cpf = input('Digite o CPF: ')
if len(cpf) < 11:
    cpf = cpf.zfill(11)
print(f'{cpf[:3]}.{cpf[3:6]}.{cpf[6:9]}-{cpf[9:]}')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/gmvdpati-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Answer (score -2):

O código abaixo aceita texto e número como entrada:

```
import re
def format_cpf(cpf):
    cpf = "{:0>11}".format(int(cpf))
    return re.sub("(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})",
                  "\\1.\\2.\\3-\\4",
                  cpf)

format_cpf("123")                  

'000.000.001-23'
```

Answer (score -3):

Olá, há várias formas de se fazer isso. Mas irei te passar uma que me ajudou a pensar mais fora da caixa!

```
cpf = (input ("CPF: "))

def formatcpf(cpf):
    vezes = 0
    novo = ""
    for quantidade in range(11):
        numero = cpf[quantidade]
        novo += numero
        vezes += 1
        if(quantidade == 8):
            novo += "-"
            vezes -= 3
        if(vezes == 3):
            novo += "."
            vezes -= 3
    return novo

print(formatcpf(cpf))
```

**Explicação:** Primeiro abri uma input que irá pegar os números de cpf que o usuário digitar, depois criei 2 variáveis: "vezes" -> que irá salvar a quantidade de vezes que o segundo loop for passado; "novo" -> que irá salvar o cpf já formatado. Criei um loop que irá ser repetido 11 vezes, que é a quantidade de números de um cpf. Dentro desse loop abri a variável "numero" que será responsável por salvar um número de cada vez do cpf temporariamente, a cada repetição 1 número de CPF é adicionado na variável novo e é somado +1 número na variável "vezes".

Posteriormente tem uma condição que será responsável por adicionar o traço do CPF na variável "novo", ela faz isso caso o número de repetições do laço seja igual a 8, decidi fazer isso pois antes dos últimos 2 números do cpf há um traço. Depois disso essa condição subtrai -3 vezes da variável "vezes". (Não se engane, pois o loop na verdade foi repetido 9 vezes, pois o range começa do 0)

A última condição é responsável por adicionar os pontos do cpf, caso o número de vezes seja igual a 3 ele irá adicionar 1 ponto na variável "novo" e subtrair -3 vezes da variável "vezes". Após isso adicionei um "return" identado antes de todos os loops, que irá ser responsável por entregar o resultado final ao usuário que será possível ser printado.

*A lógica é que a cada 3 números seja adicionado um ponto, limitado a 3 vezes e, após 9 números seja adicionado um traço que é limitado a 1 vez.*